# How to make regular expression correctly?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I need to get data from third-occurrence position of "*" to 4th. I do so:

```
    with t as (select 'T*76031*12558*test*received percents' as txt from dual)
         select regexp_replace(txt, '.*(.{4})[*][^*].*$', '\1')
    from t
```

I receive "test" - it's right, but how to get any number of characters, not just 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work given the example you have used:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( txt, '(^.*\*.*\*.*\*)([[:alnum:]]*)(\*.*$)', '\2')
```

So the SELECT would be:

```
WITH t 
  AS (SELECT 'T*76031*12558*test*received percents' AS txt FROM DUAL)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( txt, '(^.*\*.*\*.*\*)([[:alnum:]]*)(\*.*$)', '\2')
  FROM t;
```

The regex looks for:

Group 1:
start of string. Any number of characters up to a '*'. Any further characters up mto another '*'. Any further characters up to the third '*'.

Group 2:
Any alphanumeric characters

Group 3:
A '*' followed by any other characters up to the end of the string.

Replace all of the above with whatever was found in Group 2.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
Following on from a great answer from another thread by Rob van Wijk here:

[Exracting substring from given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712854/exracting-substring-from-given-string)

```
WITH t 
  AS (SELECT 'T*76031*12558*test*received percents' AS txt FROM DUAL)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( txt,'[^\*]+',1,4)
  FROM t;
```

Comment: No problemo, you could condense the group 1 pattern a little to REGEXP_REPLACE( txt, '^(.*\*){3}([[:alnum:]]*)(\*.*$)', '\2') if needed but i thought that specifying it is full was more obvious.

Comment: it doesn't work with following string: "B*44511*_____*Result in*_"

Comment: I've fixed so: "(^.*\*.*\*.*\*)([[:alnum:][:space:]]*)(\*.*$)"

Comment: I'd specify the OR operator Dmitry so it is [[:alnum:]] or [[:space:]] e.g. REGEXP_REPLACE( txt, '^(.*\*){3}(([[:alnum:]]|[[:space:]])*)(\*.*$)', '\2')

Comment: Ollie, ok, but the string can contain any character except "*"

Comment: You can specify which typers of characters it can contain in the Group 2 portion of the regex using the OR operator. Look at the bottom of this website for a full list of the character classes and use whichever you need to ensure your Group 2 recognises all the necessary characters: http://orafaq.com/node/2404

Comment: Dmitry, is there a reason why you unaccepted my answer and accepted one that is proven not to work on your indicated database?

Comment: oh, excuse me, I tested on test database  Oracle 11 g

Comment: Fair enough but you had hamstrung me somewhat tagging the question with Oracle10g. :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about the following?

```
 ^([^*]*[*]){3}([^*]*)
```

The first part matches 3 groups of * and the second part matches everything until the next * or end of line.

Comment: Pieter-Bas, and how to do only until next *?

Comment: Change the {3} into a {4}. What this regex does is from the start of the line (^) match 3 ({3}) groups of any number of non-star characters ([^*]*) followed by a single * ([*]). Then match in a second group the following sequence of non-start characters [^*]*.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that the last * of your text is also the fourth. If this assumption is true then this :

```
\b\w*\b(?=\*[^*]*$)
```

Will get you what you want. But of course this only matches the last word between * before the last star. It only matches test in this case or whatever word characters are inside the *.

Comment: @DmitryB no it returns only test because it matches only test. You can enclose the word to () if you want to use \1

Comment: @FailedDev: I'm able to get the regexp working in Perl, but not in Oracle 11g. Can you show me the code you're running ? I must have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Don't have an Oracle machine here, but it works with about every other regex flavor I can think of :s

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** 10g REGEXP_SUBSTR doesn't support returning subexpressions, see comments below.

If you are really only selecting a part of the string I recommend using [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303) instead. I don't know if it's more efficient, but it will better document your intent:

```
SQL> select regexp_substr('T*76031*12558*test*received percents', 
                          '^([^*]*[*]){3}([^*]*)', 1, 1, '', 2) from dual;

REGEXP_SUBST
------------
test
```

Above I have used regexp provided by Pieter-Bas.

See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/oracle.html

Comment: Running your SQL gives me: ORA-00939: too many arguments for funtion

Comment: @Ollie: Autch ! Cut&paste the code above works perfectly on my 11.2.0.1.0, but yes the author tagged the question with oracle10g and looks that 10g [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm#SQLRF06303) doesn't support matching subexpressions.